# Ibatis on db2 insert & update with timestamp

Tags: java, db2, ibatis

I'm working on a db2 db.

I have a table with 2 timestamp columns (start,stop).

I'm trying those operations :

```
[2014-03-17 13:19:43,576] [DEBUG] [java.sql.PreparedStatement] : {pstm-100005}     Executing Statement:       INSERT INTO WORK.MYTABLE       (        ID,        START,       STOP)       VALUES       (       ?,       ?,       ?)    
[2014-03-17 13:19:43,576] [DEBUG] [java.sql.PreparedStatement] : {pstm-100005} Parameters: [1234,2014-03-17 13:19:43.554, 2014-03-17 13:19:43.554]
[2014-03-17 13:19:43,576] [DEBUG] [java.sql.PreparedStatement] : {pstm-100005} Types: [java.lang.Long, java.sql.Timestamp, java.sql.Timestamp]


[2014-03-17 13:19:43,598] [DEBUG] [java.sql.PreparedStatement] : {pstm-100007} Executing Statement:       UPDATE WORK.MYTABLE       SET        STOP = ?       WHERE         BATCH_ID = ?    
[2014-03-17 13:19:43,598] [DEBUG] [java.sql.PreparedStatement] : {pstm-100007} Parameters: [2014-03-17 13:19:43.585, 1234]
[2014-03-17 13:19:43,598] [DEBUG] [java.sql.PreparedStatement] : {pstm-100007} Types: [java.sql.Timestamp, java.lang.Long]
```

And I got those results for start / stop :

```
After insert : 2014-03-17 13:19:43.554 / 2014-03-17 13:19:43.554
After update : 2014-03-17 13:19:43.554 / 2014-03-17 00:00:00.000
```

Why the update for a timestamp gives me 0 as time part ?

Comment: Please post full DDL, including any triggers, for the table in question.

Comment: Not enough to go on yet... I'd actually be more worried about the violation of an implied constraint - `stop` is now _before_ `start`.  You should probably have an actual db constraint for this.  A trigger is a possible culprit, given those log entries.  We need more code.

Answer (score 0):

you could use sysdate for current date and time in update, like this-

```
<update id="someId" ...>
    UPDATE "MYTABLE" SET "STOP"=sysdate where "BATCH_ID"=#id#
</update>
```

Comment: Except `SYSDATE` will only give him the date portion, so he'd still end up with a `00:00:00` time portion.